# Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

Trying to get a hasMany relationship working with Ember but running into an issue

The user json from my REST service includes usertag

```
{"user":
        [{"id":1,"name":"dolores.","email":"kuhlman@stha123n.com",
        "usertag":
                 [{"id":16,"userid":1}]}]}
```

Everything works fine for retrieving users from the store except when I try include the usertag relationship below

User.rb

```
App.User = Ember.Model.extend
    usertag: DS.hasMany('usertag')
```

Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined

Usertag.rb

```
App.Usertag = Ember.Model.extend
    userid: DS.attr 'string'
```

Can anyone see where I've made a mistake?

Thanks
!

Version info..

```
Ember      : 1.5.1+pre.07fafb84 ember.js?body=1:3524
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 ember.js?body=1:3524
Handlebars : 1.3.0 ember.js?body=1:3524
jQuery     : 1.11.0
```

Stack:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9815:23)
at Ember.Object.extend.recordForId (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9268:21)
at deserializeRecordId (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:10199:27)
at deserializeRecordIds (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:10213:9)
at http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:10179:11
at http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:8520:20
at http://localhost:3001/assets/ember.js?body=1:3431:16
at Object.OrderedSet.forEach (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember.js?body=1:3274:10)
at Object.Map.forEach (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember.js?body=1:3429:10)
at Function.Model.reopenClass.eachRelationship (http://localhost:3001/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:8519:42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your serializer, in the jSON, "usertag" should be "usertags", I think.